# MySQL / PHP - Counting Multiple Variables in WHERE part of SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP/MySQL statement:

```
$varTemp = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE
(Date1 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade1 > 224) OR
(Date2 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade2 > 224) OR
(Date3 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade3 > 224) OR
(Date4 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade4 > 224)"));
```

Right now there is an `OR` between the statements. I have also tried `UNION` and `+` but keep getting the same result. This statement SHOULD return 20 records but it only gives me 18 because there are two people who are in both the "Date1" and "Date2" statements.

My question is this: How do I change this statement to count those duplicate records?

Comment: The `Date1` and `grade1` pairing seems like the DB design should probably be reconsidered. Maybe these columns are semesters? If so I'd add a semester column then this could easily be done with `where date BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade > 244 and semester between 1 and 4`.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - although, as user3783243 suggests, this kind of problem is really indicative of poor design.

Comment: There are up to 4 dates collected for each person and each date has an associated grade. What do you suggest as an alternate design? [please don't read this as a snarky question, I'm interested to know if there's a better way to do this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of `OR` dictates that a record will only be counted once, regardless of how many parts of the `WHERE` clause are matched. If you want to double-count records that are in multiple ranges, you're on the right track with `UNION`. However, `UNION` removes duplicates by default, giving you the same result as `OR`. In your case, you probably want to use `UNION ALL`, which is the same as `UNION` but it does not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have a flaw in your logic, in order to get the result you are looking for you would need to perform multiple queries, having OR in your WHERE clause just says, if this occurs put this in the result, its a filter therefore it does not change the number of records in the table its self.

you would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    (Date1 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade1 > 224)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    (Date2 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND marker = 'Post' AND grade2 > 224)
```

and repeat for each of your 'OR's thats how you can duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your query is functionally identical to...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE 
     ( Date1 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' 
    OR Date2 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' 
    OR Date3 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' 
    OR Date4 BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
     )         
   AND marker = 'Post' 
   AND 224 IN(grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4)
```

... but if I had a query like this, I'd be redesigning my table.